# How can I schedule an email organization-specific version of Outlook on the web?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I've read instructions for the regular Outlook on the web ([Schedule an Outlook email on the web](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-schedule-email-in-outlook/)), but it seems that those steps don't apply in the organization-specific version (*school/work/etc. email accounts*). Is there a different process or additional steps to follow?

In the image below is what I see currently when trying to find the schedule option
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook on the Web *is* the organization-specific version of Microsoft Outlook. The consumer product is Outlook.com.

Your Outlook on the Web user experience including the features available to you are affected by the specific configuration of your organization's mail services.

Here are images from Outlook Web Access for an organization using    Microsoft 365 Business Premium.

**Message Preview Pane**
[image]

**Message Edit Window** 
[image]

You can see a huge difference.

If you are part of an organization that is large and has complex security/compliance/permission requirements, it is likely on a hosted Exchange infrastructure, which makes it non-trivial and process-intensive to make changes and migrate to new and improved software. Presumably the user experience is secondary to more serious concerns.

Your organization's IT department is the appropriate channel to better understand why certain features are not available to you.